# Which type of data normalizing should be used with KNN?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, standardization, k-nearest-neighbour

I know that there is more than two type of normalizing.

For example,

1- Transforming data using a z-score or t-score. This is usually called standardization.

2- Rescaling data to have values between 0 and 1.

The question now if I need normalizing

Which type of data normalizing should be used with KNN? and Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For k-NN, I'd suggest **normalizing** the data between $0$ and $1$.

k-NN uses the **Euclidean distance**, as its means of comparing examples. To calculate the distance between two points $x_1 = (f_1^1, f_1^2, ..., f_1^M)$ and  $x_2 = (f_2^1, f_2^2, ..., f_2^M)$, where $f_1^i$ is the value of the $i$-th feature of $x_1$:

$$
d(x_1, x_2) = \sqrt{(f_1^1 - f_2^1)^2 + (f_1^2 - f_2^2)^2 + ... + (f_1^M - f_2^M)^2}
$$

In order for **all** of the features to be of **equal** importance when calculating the distance, the features **must** have the same range of values. This is only achievable through normalization.

If they were not normalized and for instance feature $f^1$ had a range of values in $[0, 1$), while $f^2$ had a range of values in $[1, 10)$. When calculating the distance, the second term would be $10$ times important than the first, leading k-NN to rely more on the second feature than the first. Normalization ensures that **all** features are mapped to the **same** range of values.

Standardization, on the other hand, does have many useful properties, but **can't** ensure that the features are mapped to the same range. While standardization may be best suited for other classifiers, this is not the case for k-NN or any other distance-based classifier.

Comment: Is your answer will be the same if I used different distance instead of Euclidean distance (for example Manhattan distance or other distance even fractional distance)? Also If the range of the variables is approximately close to each other.

Comment: Yes I just showed Euclidean distance as an example, but all distance metrics suffer from the same thing. If the ranges are close to one another then it wouldn't affect the calculation of the metric **that much**, but it still would. For example if $f^1 \in [0, 1)$ and $f^2 \in [0, 1.2)$, $f^2$ would still be $20\%$ more important than $f^1$. One thing I forgot to mention was that standardizing, obviously, is much better than not performing any feature scaling; it is simply worse than normalization.

Comment: Ah I see. "it is simply worse than normalization"!?